# dismissed Dissmisible widget is still part of the tree error

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a problem with Dismissible widget. I use that to close actual page by calling a function:

```
onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop().
```

so what I did: wrap whole scaffold by Dismissible.

Everything worked fine until delivered to the page state with bool information about the logged in user (admin or no).
Now i get error like this:

> FlutterError (A dismissed Dissmisible widget is still part of the
> tree.  Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to
> immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once
> that has fired.)

Screen: [ErrorScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc3Rx.jpg)

I tried "key" changes but it didn't help.

Page code with Dismissible:

```
class OtherDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OtherDetailsPage({required this.id, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String id;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          OtherDetailsCubit(OtherRemoteDataSource())..getDetailsWithID(id),
      child: BlocBuilder<OtherDetailsCubit, OtherDetailsState>(
        builder: (context, details) {
          final detail = details.detailsState;
          return BlocBuilder<RootCubit, RootState>(
            builder: (context, root) {
              bool? admin = root.admin;

              if (admin == null || detail == null) {
                return const LoadingPage();
              }
              return Dismissible(
                key: const Key('key'),
                // key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
                direction: DismissDirection.down,
                onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Scaffold(
                    body: Column(
                  children: [
                    Header(detail: detail),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    DetailsDescription(detail: detail),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    admin
                        ? SwitchValueButton(id: id, detail: detail)
                        : const SizedBox(
                            height: 1,
                          ),
                    const AnimatedArrowDown()
                  ],
                )),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a UniqueKey?

Comment: Yes, but then there is another problem: the animation on the page does not play smoothly and the screen cannot be pulled down - it does not respond to dragging...